# search for file and read from it dependent on input in C

Tags: c

I'm stuck as to why the below doesn't work...

> If filename entered matches -> display file
>
> If filename entered does not match file then exit with error code.

currently no matter what i input it always displays the file...

```
int c;
int str;
FILE *file;
int main(void);

   fprintf(stdout, "Please input a file you would like to retrieve\n");
    str = getchar();
    
    if(str = "success.txt")
    {
        file = fopen("success.txt", "r");
       if (file) {
            while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
                putchar(c);
                fclose(file);
}
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "The file you have requested does not exist\n");
    }
```

i've also tried using fscanf for the exact same result. can anyone point me in the right direction?

could i use something like below?

```
char* path = "success.txt"; 
int rval; 
/* Check file existence. */ 
rval = access (path, F_OK); 
if (rval == 0) 
return 0 ; 
    else { if (errno == ENOENT) 
    { fprintf (stderr, "%s does not exist program will now exit", path);   
exit(0);
}
}
```

thank you

Comment: Are you using a debugger? Are you familiar with the purpose of the functions you tend to use? Did you read the man pages? etc.

Comment: could i use something like `char* path = "success.txt"; 
  int rval; 
 
  /* Check file existence.  */ 
  rval = access (path, F_OK); 
  if (rval == 0) 
      return 0 ;
  else {
    if (errno == ENOENT) 
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "%s does not exist program will now exit", path);
      exit(0);` and input path variable from scanf?? @Barracuda

Comment: you may add that in the description of your question not in the comment. As it is your question is a low quality question that's asking for debugging help. Use a debugger before asking a question here. It's really simple.

Comment: okay thanks, still sort of new.. appreciate it. @Barracuda

Comment: This code doesn't compile. We can't reproduce the symptoms...

Comment: why are you checking the file name instead of trying to open the file and check the return value and `errno` immediately? Is there a particular reason for your design? Why not hard-coding the file name if it's not going to change?

Comment: did any of the answers below help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are getting the character from the user. But you are checking that with `string`.

Use `fgets` get the input from the user.

```
 char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);

 int len=stlen(array)-1;
 if ( len > 0 && array[len] == '\n' )
          array[len] ='\0';
```

While you need to compare that file , then use `strcmp` function.

```
 if ( strcmp(array,"success.txt\n") == 0 )
```

---

Comment: `array[strlen(array)] == '\n'`? I hope not!

Comment: fgets will add the new line after getting the input. So if you tried to compare that array new line will be placed in that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check the file name entered by the user. You can try opening the file and if it fails (`fopen()` returning a `NULL`) then your desired file is either inaccessible (you don't have enough privileges) or the file simply does not exist. Checking the value of `errno` will tell you what exactly went wrong. Also I don't understand why you ask the user for a file name and then compare it against a hard-coded name. If you want a file with a constant name then hard-coding is a better option. Why ask the user if the name really matters and is not going to change?! Your design is flawed altogether. You don't need to do all this just to see the correctness of the entered file name.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the assignment operator in

```
if( str = "success.txt" )
```

And not the equality conditional ( `"=="` )

EDIT: As in the comments, for strings, the equality conditional doesn't work and you ought to use `strcmp()`.

The assignment operator evaluates to true since it was able to successfully assign the value.

EDIT: The assignment operator evaluates to true because it assigned a non-zero value, not because it successfully assigned it.

Comment: jesus, thank you, something so simple that i overlooked.

also looked at implementing `char* path = "success.txt"; int rval; /* Check file existence. */ rval = access (path, F_OK); if (rval == 0) return 0 ; else { if (errno == ENOENT) { fprintf (stderr, "%s does not exist program will now exit", path); exit(0);`

Comment: Kathikeyan also has a valid input that might come up as an error after you fix this one.

Comment: Note that == is also wrong, since you need to use strcmp to compare strings, not ==. Also, to clarify: the expression doesn't evaluate to true because it was able to successfully assign the value, but because the value assigned was non-zero.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy i see your point and after trying to run it you're correct. will try implementing Karthikeyan's solution.